# How to add unique id that stays the same when refreshing data in Power Query?

Tags: excel, indexing, powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm struggling with assigning a unique id to a row that would stay the same after refresh. I'm using an index column and I'm appending two tables. When I add an entry to main table, id's rearrange.

How to make Power Query load new data at the end of the appended tables? Or is the other way to do this?

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({emp_info_pomocnicza, rekrutacja_employees}),
    #"Added Index Column" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Źródło, "Indeks", 0, 1)
in
    #"Added Index Column"
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible.

Comment: Can you create a unique key by combining columns? If not, there is probably no way to do this

Comment: I vote for @horseyride, and I don't think of any reason a persistent surrogate key has to be created inside Power Query. Surrogate keys should be only purposed to make relationships inside Data Model, and for this purpose, it should be OK that the key is reassigned every time dataset is refreshed.